# Can't connect MongoDB to Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am a total newbie in Web App development, and today I followed this YouTube video tutorial to connect MongoDB to Node.js: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhiEJW5poHU.

I followed everything in the Youtube video and here are my code, which I follow exactly from the tutorial:

server.js

```
/* Connect to MongoDB database */
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const MongoDBpassword = process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD
const uri = `mongodb+srv://giangpham:${MongoDBpassword}@cluster0.q22wdfo.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

async function connect() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(uri)
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB")
  } catch(error) {
    console.log("Error connecting to MongoDB: ", error)
  }
}

connect()
```

However, I can't connect it and this is the error I got: `Error connecting to MongoDB:  MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/`

I tried using the sample code from the MongoDB website:

```
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://giangpham:<password>@cluster0.q22wdfo.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

// Create a MongoClient with a MongoClientOptions object to set the Stable API version
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  serverApi: {
    version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
    strict: true,
    deprecationErrors: true,
  }
});

async function run() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
    await client.connect();
    // Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
    await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!");
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

and this is the error I got:
`MongoServerSelectionError: read ECONNRESET at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/giangpham/Desktop/writer-cave/writer_cave/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:278:38) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:568:17) at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:511:7) { reason: TopologyDescription { type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary', servers: Map(3) { 'ac-w1pnlco-shard-00-01.q22wdfo.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription], 'ac-w1pnlco-shard-00-02.q22wdfo.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription], 'ac-w1pnlco-shard-00-00.q22wdfo.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription] }, stale: false, compatible: true, heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000, localThresholdMS: 15, setName: 'atlas-13ubyp-shard-0', maxElectionId: null, maxSetVersion: null, commonWireVersion: 0, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null }, code: undefined, [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}`

Comment: If you follow MongoDB's [Node.js Quick Start Tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-start/), do you have better success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first error, The most common reason for this error is that the IP address you're trying to connect from is not on the IP whitelist for your MongoDB Atlas cluster.
There are a few reasons for the second one, It will be best if you can whitelist your IP.

Set up - Visit the MongoDB Atlas dashboard and log in. Navigate to the "Network Access" section, and now add this IP, by which you can access from any IP.

[image]